# Amazon DynamoDB ProvisionedThroughputExceededException (iOS SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB. I do scan operations from the app. Everything works perfect. After sometime, the response is coming as nil. But I am not receiving any exceptions. I enabled verbose logging using,

```
[AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
```

If the verbose logging is enabled, I can see some logs like,

> "__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20111205#ProvisionedThroughputExceededException","message":"The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API"

My code looks like this,

```
@try {
    DynamoDBScanRequest *request = /* Create request */;
    DynamoDBScanResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager ddb] scan:request];
    /* 
     * response is nil if the provisioning throughput is exceeded 
     * and the all retries are over
     */
    ALog(@"Response: %@", response); 
    NSMutableArray *array = response.items;
    return array;
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    /* 
     * I am expecting the  ProvisionedThroughputExceededException 
     * to be thrown here. But its not throwing here. Instead I get the response
     * as nil above.
     */
    ALog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
    return nil;
}
```

Am I doing it correct? Could someone help me please?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Could anyone give me a rough idea of how much throughput (both read/write) capacity to set for a QuestionAnswer table, with almost 10 fields like TopicID, QuestionID, Question, Answer, AskedAt, RepliedAt, QuestionType etc.,? Thanks.

Comment: DynamoDB is priced based on the amount of provisioned throughput you have configured, you are accessing it more frequently than your setup has indicated and you're being throttled. You need to consider if you actually need to scan the table, a scan will inspect the entire table which results in high throughput, if this is the first NoSQL DB you've used you should do some investigation into how best to use them, you can't just perform ad hoc queries like RDB, they're expensive in terms of time and resources. Consider managing indexes that would allow explicit gets as separate tables.

Comment: Thanks. You mean there is no way I will get the exception thrown to the @catch block if I use Scan?

Comment: Do you see the earlier Response ALog messages, to be sure your logging is configured correctly? If you put a break in the catch does it trigger before you get nil or is nil definitely being returned from the try block? I've not used the AWS iOS SDK for Dynamo, but have had experience of some of their other APIs not always performing as expected, so if you're never entering your catch block it may be that their sdk is swallowing the exception earlier. Could be worth trying to add a global exception handler to see if anything crops up there.

Comment: I am sure ALog works good. It does log some other exceptions. But in the above try/catch block, I tried putting breakpoints inside catch block. But it never gets into it. I will try the global exception handler. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, may be worth raising the issue on the AWS forums to get their opinion too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried a scan request with more read capacity units than provisioned, and I got `AmazonClientException` with a generic message: "Unknown error occurred." We are working on a fix, and the next version should correctly return `DynamoDBProvisionedThroughputExceededException` in the described situation.

You said the response becomes nil, but I was not able to reproduce the issue. Do you call `[AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions]` to turn off the exceptions? When this option is turned on, the SDK won't throw `AmazonClientException` and `AmazonServiceException`. It is also possible that you are using an older version of the SDK. Please try 1.4.4 and see if you get the exception. It is suboptimal, but at least you should be able to catch an exception when something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Okay. Consider I prefer to modify the throughput using AWS Console, and my app is in store. What will happen if the throughput limit is exceeded and I am not available to modify the throughput? My users will not be able to work with the app smoothly? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The experience of your app users depends on how you handle when the app receives an exception, or receives nil in your case. In either case, you should gracefully handle them; for instance, the app can wait for a little while and automatically retry, or gracefully fail and notify the user.

As a general guideline, I strongly recommend provisioning enough capacity units and setting a CloudWatch alert so that you can receive notifications and bump the capacity units before the app starts seeing the `DynamoDBProvisionedThroughputExceededException`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. Thanks. App will throw DynamoDBProvisionedThroughputExceededException as soon as the capacity is exceeded or it takes some time, I mean 15min, 1hr or something? Could you please tell me what would be an enough capacity for a QuestionAnswer table, with almost 10 fields like TopicID, QuestionID, Question, Answer, AskedAt, RepliedAt, QuestionType etc., I am really thankful for your responses.

Comment: [Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guid](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks. I would have not asked you this question if I could understand the developer guide. I didn't mean that the guide is bad, I just mean that I don't understand. Anyway, thanks for your time.